Telegram bot api click on message containing button
I have a private chat in telegram and there I have two bots
One of the bots is mine and other is not mine and it can send messages with buttons.
Is it possible for my bot to click on this button?(for example can it click on upscale 4x button  )?
(see screenshot below)
Hope my queston is clear. I use python if it matters.Also I  know how to send normal message in dialog with bot api, but don't know if it is possible for bot to press btn


Unfortunately, no. Bots cannot see or interact with messages sent by other bots. This is stated in Telegram Bot FAQ.
So, the simple answer is no, you cannot make your bot press the Upscale inline button sent by the other bot.

But, there's a catch. You can programmatically do this with MTProto or the Telegram API - which can be used to create user bots or Telegram client apps. A good library in python for this is pyrogram.
Particularly, you might be interested in the messages.getBotCallbackAnswer method. Please check further docs here:

Official Telegram Documentation
Pyrogram Docs


Solution with Pyrogram
from pyrogram import Client, filters, types

api_id = 12345
api_hash = "<your api hash>"

app = Client("my_account", api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash)

@app.on_message(filters.group)
async def hello(client: Client, message: types.Message):
    is_bot = message.from_user.is_bot
    if not is_bot:
        print("Message not from a bot")
        return
    
    has_keyboard = message.reply_markup != None and message.reply_markup.inline_keyboard != None

    if not has_keyboard:
        print("Message does not have a keyboard")
        return
    
    # Retrieve the callback data of Upscale 4x button (Row 0, Col 1)
    data = message.reply_markup.inline_keyboard[0][1].callback_data

    result = await client.request_callback_answer(
        chat_id=message.chat.id,
        message_id=message.id, 
        callback_data=data
    )

    # Result will be of type `types.messages.BotCallbackAnswer`
    print(result)

app.run()

This is a simple example, make sure to customize as you need it. Basically, this code listens for all incoming messages in all of your groups and supergroups. When a bot sends a message with InlineKeyboard, you'll automatically taps the "second button on the first row" (I hard-coded this based on the screenshot you've given in the question).
Hope this makes sense and hope this helps :)

can you provide code example please - i am reading docs but still don't understand how I can use it

hey, i've updated the answer with some code. make sure to tailor it for your needs :)
